# How to calc Win Rate in SQL?

Tags: sql, sqlite, sum, pivot, average

I am trying to calculate win rate for the below table in SQL but not getting a correct answer

[image]

What I am looking for is WON = 1111/1496*100

So far i've got

```
SELECT Sum( Status = 'Won') /(Select Count(Status))*100 as Win_rate
FROM table
```

If i run the above it gives me `0`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is integer division. Both operands of the division are integers, so SQLite forces an integer result. A typical workaround is force decimal context, like:

```
SELECT 100.0 * sum(Status = 'Won') / Count(*) as Win_rate FROM mytable
```

But it is simpler to use `avg()` here:

```
SELECT avg(Status = 'Won') * 100 as Win_rate
FROM mytable
```